# Restore from PostgreSQL custom dump file using Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, liquibase

Our team currently uses a custom database version control system. We are contemplating on moving to Liquibase.

Currently, after each release, we pg_dump the schema (without production data) into a custom (--format=c) data file. This data file is restored into development instances as part of the  build (through a maven plugin provided by the custom DB version control system). We would like to continue using the custom data file format (since it restores faster resulting in faster development builds).

I get the impression that Liquibase supports restoring from a plain text SQL file but not from a custom format file. Is this correct?

Comment: The purpose of liquibase is to manage the schema, not the data. So using an alternate tool for loading data is probably best advised.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that it does't support a custom formats, just CSV. You can use [executeCommand](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/execute_command.html), however, to call out to whatever program can load data using the files.